# Ubuntu Wont Start Up, any Suggestions?

Tags: boot, dependencies, postfix, 21.04, error-handling

These are the following  messages  I receive when I boot up my computer:

```
/dev/sda2:clean, 567436/30049216 files, 10011641/12112000 blocks
[FAILED] FAILED to start Light Display  Manager
[   39.002848] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'                    
[FAILED] FAILED to start Light Display Manager
[FAILED] FAILED to start Light Display Manager
[FAILED] FAILED to start Light Display Manager
[FAILED] FAILED to start Light Display Manager 
[FAILED] FAILED to start Light Display Manager
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD NSS Service responder socket

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD Auto FS Service responder socket

[DEPEND] Dependency failed for SSSD PAC Service responder  socket.

[DEPEND] Dependency  failed for SSSD PAM Service  responder socket 

[DEPEND] Dependency  failed for SSSD PAM Service responder socket

[DEPEND] Dependency  failed for SSSD SSH Service responder  socket 

[DEPEND] Dependency  failed for SSSD Sudo Service  responder socket

[FAILED] Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)
[DEPEND]
```

I Recieved the error after trying to reinstall system packages that the terminal was removing during my upgrade to 21.04, however I noticed that it was the new packages it was deleting  so I killed the process halfway through. I was reinstalling the files it deleted and I was greeted with this error.Now I will say that what I did was likely  not the smatest thing to do.Just throwing that out there.I am still able to access the console,though  I'm struggling  to remember  my Linux ID to access it.I am mostly looking how to resolve those errors, but if you guys are able to provide  a solution  to the login problem  I will also be grateful for that.Thank you

Comment: If you have interrupted the upgrade process, you probably ***can*** fix it, but you might find it much easier to reinstall.  If you boot from a live USB and do the TryUbuntu, you can access your disks to backup data before installing just to be sure that your data is not going to be erased.

Comment: Okay.Is there a potential  way I could get TryUbuntu on my phone and then transfer the data that way? Or will I have to reinstall the software that was on the disk when I fist start the machine?

Comment: "Try Ubuntu" is a live session. Meaning: Boot from a USB installation media like you did when you installed the system.